# Disabling predictive text on windows phone (HTML/JS)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I'm developing a universal Windows application for Windows Phone on HTML and JS and I'd need to disable predictive text/automatic suggestions for an HTML input field.

So far, I've tried adding `autocomplete="off"` and `inputmode="predictOff"`, but Windows Phone keyboard still keeps showing suggestions. Is there any way of showing the keyboard without predictive text?

Comment: I wonder if you were able to find a solution? Also, I wonder if you know how to track insertion of chunks of predicted text into the inputbox as they get selected from predicted words? "onkeydown" or "onkeyup" don't seem to capture them and "onchange" is only triggered upon losing focus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML world you can use the InputScope with its enumeration to specify the keyboard to use, some have the suggestions and others don't. In an app using HTML/JavaScript the keyboard is determined by the type of the HTML input control. The only one that doesn't have the suggestions is the password type, which is pretty useless because it doesn't show text.

I hope someone could prove me wrong, but as far as I know you can't turn the suggestions off.